# Macbook acting weird

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, mail.app, time-machine

My 2015 Macbook pro 13" is acting weird, after restoring from a Time Machine backup my mac is running slow and I have a lot of bugs:

The reaction time of the system is very slow, sometimes when I open a new tab or when I write in this textfield, I just see the spinning beach ball for a couple of seconds.

The mail app can't connect to my three gmails, but my iCloud mail is running fine,
Every time I activate Find my Mac it just deactivates after a second.

Hope some of you can solve at least one of the questions

Update:
Many apps (Safari Photos Notes and other) is openning at the same screen every time, (safari at the same 5 specific tabs, Photos at the same pic, and notes at the same sub folder)

I restored March 1. and the slow reaction time started earlier today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, used this command in terminal `chmod -RN ~/Library/`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like spotlight is indexing the disk.
Have a look at the cpu usage in "activity monitor" to make sure. The culprits should be processes named "mds" and/or "mdworker"

If it is spotlight indeed this will take a while (hours). Be patient ;-)

Comment: spotlight is not indexing,( mdworker and mds is totally about 2% of CPU) it's about two days ago I restored.